# One line initialization of array using a structure

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to initialize an array of a structure which contains 2 variables inside.

```
Private Structure SnakeLocation
    Public Row As Integer
    Public Column As Integer
End Structure
```

I have tried the following, but neither work.

```
Private Position As SnakeLocation() = New SnakeLocation() With {.Row = 7, .Column = 8}
Private Position() As SnakeLocation = New SnakeLocation With {.Row = 7, .Column = 8}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

```
Dim Position As SnakeLocation() = New SnakeLocation() { new SnakeLocation With {.Row = 7, .Column = 8} }
```

First you create the array and initialize it with a SnakeLocation that is than initialized with the values.

Comment: Interesting, is there a page I can view that explains how this works? Thank you for the answer by the way, I was stuck on this for a while.

Comment: @Yezetee Yes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable

Comment: Would this also be possible using a list? Something like this:     `Private Position1 As New List(Of SnakeLocation)(New SnakeLocation  {.Row = 7, .Column = 8})`

Comment: @Yezetee Yes, any collection with an `Add` function.